# Display details in a textbox

Tags: c#

I have a list box.Whenever I search a person from the database, the result will be displayed in a listbox. Then what I want is whenever I click on the name of the person from the listbox is that the persons detail will be displayed in textboxes. I have my code but the problem is that only the details of the person I first click are displayed in the textboxes.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
        select.Connection = connection;
        select.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts";
        OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader[0].ToString() == listBox1.Tag.ToString())
            {
                fnametb.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                lnametb.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                agetb.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                addresstb.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                coursetb.Text = reader[5].ToString();
            }

        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You're referencing `listBox1.Tag.ToString()` instead of the selected list box item.

Comment: is the `listBox1.Tag.ToString()` and `listBox1.selectedItem.ToString()` the same?

Comment: change it to `listBox1.selectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your code you need to refresh `listBox1.Tag` and put into `Tag` Selected list box item key. Or you need to use something like `reader[0].ToString() ==listBox1.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
if (reader[0].ToString() == listBox1.Tag.ToString())
it will not work....
```

you need to get the selected index of a list box

Answer (score 0):

change it to `listBox1.selectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the `ListBox.Tag` instead of the `ListBox.SelectedItem`.

> > The Tag property can be used to store any object that you want to associate with an item. Although you can store any item, the Tag property is typically used to store string information about the item, such as a unique identifier or the index position of the item's data in a database.

You could simply check the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx) since you are in the `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event anyway.

Instead of

```
if (reader[0].ToString() == listBox1.Tag.ToString())
```

try

```
if (reader[0].ToString() == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Answer (score -1):

your Select Query must have some parameters like WHERE clause so the program would know what specific data in the database will it load.

Tell me what is the display in your listbox ?

This is just another option.